# Действие перед тем как изменить размер окна

Tags: c#, wpf, события

Здравствуйте, как словить событие изменения размера окна? Я имею ввиду что бы в окне происходили определённые действия **перед тем**, как `WindowState` станет `Maximized`, вне зависимости от того, каким образом `WindowState` станет `Maximized`.

Comment: [Судя по всему, только через P/Invoke](http://stackoverflow.com/a/928798/276994).

Comment: А действительно ли необходимо событие перед изменением окна? Может быть все можно сделать по событию SizeChanged?

Comment: @zuev93 , да, именно перед тем как изменить состояние окна необходимо произвести определённые действия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    private const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                int command = wParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
                if (command == SC_MINIMIZE) {
                   //before min
                } else {
                   //before max
                }
                break;
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    private void Window_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr windowHandle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
        HwndSource src = HwndSource.FromHwnd(windowHandle);
        src.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
    }
```

код внутри SourceInitialized лучше исполнять именно внутри этого события или любого другого, когда окно уже про инициализировано ибо

```
 (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle
```

будет выдывать 0 пока оно не инициализируется

Comment: сделал всё как вы написали, но почему-то с этим кодом программа ведёт себя как-то странно. Суть в чём, у меня есть `Border`, он служит верхней панелью моей программы, соответственно при зажатой на нём клавиши мыши выполняется функция `DragMove()`, но с добавлением этого кода окно просто разворачивается на весь экран при элементарном нажатии мыши на этот `Border`. Код смотрите ниже.

Comment: так правильно я вам немного фигню скинул, дело в том, что в else будет сваливаться не только разворачивание окна...в общем вот ссылка на winUser.h там можно найти все значения которые может принимать wParam http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~gfrancis/illimath/windows/aszgard_mini/bin/MinGW/include/winuser.h т.е. в данном случае надо объявить SC_MAXIMIZE 0xF030 и else вообще убрать, окно у вас разворачивается потому, что вы явно вызываете WindowState = WindowState.Maximized

Comment: Я вместо `private const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;` сделал `private const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030;` , и писал всё в `if (command == SC_MAXIMIZE) {}`, но он не работает почему-то... Не подскажите в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А что не работает, код который по этому условию должен сработать? Точку после установите int command = wParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0; и посмотрите какое значение в переменной command  храниться и равно ли оно SC_MAXIMIZE, по крайней мере перед тем как коммент выше написать я создавал тестовый WPF проект, все работало)

Comment: вот что получилось при присвоении значения переменной command:  [переменная command](http://cs622218.vk.me/v622218033/49939/s7saS0AwxCE.jpg), [переменная SC_MAXIMIZE](http://cs622218.vk.me/v622218033/49943/sYKiA1PpP-I.jpg).

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov а вы как максимизируете окно? Если дабл кликом по рамке, сначала будет 0xF010, что есть 61456 в dec (это движение окна), а следом сработает событие уже с 0xF030, если нажать кнопку "максимизировать" тогда сразу сработает с 0xF030  воткните чтонибуть вроде #if DEBUG
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("значение command = {0}", command));
#endif и посмотрите что выводиться при максимизации

Comment: я максимизирую его перетаскиванием к верху экрана.

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov странно, видимо Aero Snap по другому окно максимизирует, но все равно через WinApi отловить это можно, немного переиграл, вот http://pastebin.com/sijXxqh6

Answer (score 1):

```
    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    private const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;

    private void music_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr windowHandle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
        HwndSource src = HwndSource.FromHwnd(windowHandle);
        src.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
    }

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                int command = wParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
                if (command == SC_MINIMIZE)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    border_main.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(0);
                    border_bottom.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(0);
                    ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
                    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                }
                break;
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```